# Weird result with UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, union

I have this query (simplified):

```
SELECT score FROM tbl WHERE id = xx ORDER BY score DESC;
```

And it works correctly. Now I add to this query an `UNION` like this:

```
(SELECT score FROM tbl WHERE id = x ORDER BY score DESC)
   UNION
(SELECT score FROM tbl WHERE id = y)
```

Now all the first result-set of the first query is messed up not respecting the `ORDER BY score DESC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT score FROM tbl WHERE id = x 
   UNION
SELECT score FROM tbl WHERE id = y

ORDER BY score DESC;

just add the order by to the end. it will apply to the entire result set. If you want to differentiate the result add an order col like so:

SELECT 1 as order_col, score FROM tbl WHERE id = x 
   UNION
SELECT 2 as order_col, score FROM tbl WHERE id = y

ORDER BY order_col ,score DESC;

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I can have duplicate rows because they can have different score field.. How can i solve this? Maybe a final group by id?

Answer (score 1):

In a union query, the order by must be put with the last select.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution.

UNION and ORDER BY isn't allowed. I can only put ORDER BY at the end of UNION