# MYSQL SELECT with one entry at the end

Tags: mysql

Stackoverflowers,
I want to select from a MYSQL table and show ID 54 in the end of the MYSQL query, I made the following code but it conflicts with the ORDER:

```
SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id <= 53
UNION
SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id >= 55
ORDER BY owner
UNION
SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id = 54
```

I think it is very buggy even if it worked, can you help?

Comment: how do you mean "it conflicts with the order"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to put 54 at the end, perhaps you could shortened your query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM owners 
WHERE id <= 53 or id >= 55 or id = 54
ORDER BY 
   id = 54, 
   owner
```

False sorts first, true sorts last. Other database do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM owners 
WHERE id <= 53 or id >= 55 or id = 54
ORDER BY 
   case when id = 54 then 1 else 0 end, 
   owner
```

But that is funny, remove the condition altogether:

```
SELECT * FROM owners 

ORDER BY 
   case when id = 54 then 1 else 0 end, 
   owner
```

Comment: Your query will return `0` rows ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it should be OR, not AND; heheh, why I think of BETWEEN. Thanks for spotting it quick ツ

Comment: Even with `OR` instead of `AND` you're filtering out `ID = 54`... Why do you have that predicate anyway?

Comment: And you should remove the `WHERE` part.

Comment: Oops, short-circuited. Let me make that explicit. Really, his query's WHERE condition could be all removed

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on the order of a `UNION`'s subselect. See also many other Stack Overflow questions, such as this one:

[Weird result with UNION and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491621/weird-result-with-union-and-order-by)

Do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM owners
-- Order by "ID category" first
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID <= 53 THEN 1
              WHEN ID >= 55 THEN 2
              WHEN ID  = 54 THEN 3 END,
-- Then, within "category 55", order by owner, too
         CASE WHEN ID <= 53 THEN ''
              WHEN ID >= 55 THEN owner
              WHEN ID  = 54 THEN '' END
```

You may have to slightly adapt that second `ORDER BY` expression, as I'm not really sure what you want to do with that ordering by `owner`...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your example you want to select everything from `owners` and display the row with `id=54` <strike>first</strike> last.

```
SELECT * FROM owners 
order by case id when 54 then 1 else 0 end, id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use parentheses

```
(SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id <= 53)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id >= 55 ORDER BY owner)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM owners WHERE id = 54)
```

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491621/weird-result-with-union-and-order-by